# How to make two-way CSS3 animation

Tags: css, animation

**Goal:**
Achieve animation that

- apply initial style
- on adding some class it plays forwards and keeps resulting styles
- on removing trigger class it plays backwards and returns to initial state

**What i got:**

```
@keyframes translate {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  }
}
.element {
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-duration: 0.35s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: translate;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.element.is-animated {
  animation-direction: normal;
}
```

**Result:**

It works as described above, (keeps style as required) except the lack of smooth animation. Just switches styles instantly. I guess there are some rules overlapping.

**Does anybody made the same? I haven't find any proper tutorial for this particular issue**

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Work both on Gecko and Webkit engines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to switch between only this two transform properties. Use transition instead of animation.

```
.element {
    transition:transform .2s ease;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid red;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }
  .element.is-animated {
    transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
  }
```

Precisely you should add remove the class is-animated, whenever you want the transition to take place