# Slide down/up animation

Tags: css, css-animations

In this snippet, using keyframes and animation and display none/block, the div animates to slide down on hover.

```css
h1 { padding: 20px; }
div {
    width: 100%; background: pink; padding: 20px;
    
    display: none;
}

body:hover div {
    display: block;
    
    -webkit-animation: slide-down .3s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: slide-down .3s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-down {
      0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }   
    100% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-down {
      0% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }   
    100% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0); }
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
<h1>Hover me</h1>
```

How can it be made to also slide back up when hover is removed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make two-way CSS3 animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398698/how-to-make-two-way-css3-animation)

Comment: I tried doing what was proposed in this answer but I could not make it work.  It wasn't sliding at all actually.

Comment: It's difficult to achieve with animation. But you can do it with transition instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try applying the transition property to the actual element:

```css
h1 { padding: 20px; }
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; background: pink; padding: 20px;  
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

body:hover div {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
<h1>hover me</h1>
```

Comment: I don't want it to take up any space before is slides down.  I actually pulled my example from this: https://jsfiddle.net/simurai/A9kWm/.  Not sure why it isn't working the same way in my snippet here that it does on jsfiddle.

Comment: then set position to absolute